# Explode string with '/' and escape if it contains space around '/', like ' / '

Tags: php, regex

How is it possible to explode a string using '/', if slash doesn't contain spaces before or after.

I wish the string like "Flat Visors / Fitted Caps" could be treated as a string and "Flat Visors/Fitted Caps" could be explode using '/'.

Comment: you can use `explode("/", $string)` ...

Comment: Can you explain more clear or show what you have tried

Comment: @pes502 I think that will still explode slashes when there's spaces around them.

Comment: @pes502: you are correct how can I avoid this.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `preg_split` with negative look-behind and negative look-ahead:

```
preg_split('/(?<!\s)\\/(?!\s)/', $str);
```

If you wish the opposite, i.e. splitting even when there is space around and remove the space, again with `preg_split` and optional space:

```
preg_split('/\s*\\/\s*/', $str);
```

Comment: Or simpler `~\S/\S~`